# Dreamweaver code editor is there "Select parent tag" feature. l am not found Jedit. Is there it?

Tags: dreamweaver, jedit

Dreamweaver is in "select parent tag" property.

Is there property in jedit? Plugin etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XML plugin](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?XML) has a "Select element or code block" action which looks like it does the same as the dreamweaver item i.e. it selects the tags enclosing the caret/selection and everything within them.